# FPGA Logic Gate Count

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, xilinx, spartan

I found an FPGA board that I liked. It uses a Xilinx Spartan 6 LX45. When I went to the [datasheet for the Spartan 6 series](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds160.pdf), it only said that there were 43,661 logic cells. How many gates does that equate to? Or rther, how would I figure out the number of total gates from the number of logic cells?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FPGA manufacturers don't use equivalent gate counts much any more, even in the hand-wavyest marketing materials. Like lines of code or megahertz of processor speed, it's a highly inaccurate metric for measuring the device capability, and in the FPGA markets the customers wised up enough to suppress its use.

To estimate the size device you need, you'll need to look at the summary on p. 2 of the datasheet you linked. Usually you can get a decent idea early on in your design process how many flip-flops, how many i/o's and how much ram your design needs. One or the other of those will typically be the critical resource that determines the size of part you need.

If you aren't tightly cost-constrained, use a device 2x or more bigger than you think you need. It will give you room for feature creep in your design and also speeds up development because the design tools won't need to work so hard to fit your design into the available resources.

**Edit**, pulling in things from comments,

You mentioned that your design is mostly unclocked.

The issue with this is that FPGA design tools depend on clocking and the resulting timing constraints to drive optimization of the synthesized design. If you want to do unclocked design in an FPGA it's possible in principle, but you're not going to get much help from the tools (or vendors) and you'll probably need to find a specialized community who do that kind of thing to get any support.

In any case, you can look at the Spartan 6 [Configurable Logic Block User's Guide](http://xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug384.pdf) to see what resources are available in each block. Then mentally map your design to those resource to see how many blocks you need. That should be enough to let you pick the right size device.

For example, you can see in that document that the LX45 part contains about 27,000 6-input LUTs. Each LUT can be used to implement an arbitrary combinatorial logic with up to 6 inputs. If you can express your logic in terms of this primitive, you can estimate whether your design fits into the device.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I still haven't started designing (and my design is directly in logic), because, I was going to design based on my FPGAs special offerings. I know I would need roughly >2.5M gates, so how would I find something that could hold that many gates?

Comment: Really, no flip-flops?

Comment: Well, I have some, but quite a few are just SR and other ones, instead of JK and D.

Comment: To get good support from FPGA synthesis tools you may want to consider adjusting your design to emphasize D flip-flops --- I suppose there are ways to design in other styles, but the FPGA toolsets are heavily oriented toward RTL design, meaning lots of Dff's.

Comment: The thing with D flip-flops is that they're clocked, which isn't something I really like in my design. But either way, what should I do to find the number of cells I'd need?

Comment: The thing about FPGA design tools is that they depend on clocking and the resulting timing constraints to drive optimization of the synthesized design. If you want to do unclocked design in an FPGA you probably can, but you're not going to get much help from the tools (or vendors) and you'll probably need to find a specialized community who do that kind of thing to get any support.

Comment: In any case, you can look at the Spartan 6 Configurable Logic Block User's guide to see what resources are available in each block. Then mentally map your design to those resource to see how many blocks you need. That should be enough to let you pick the right size device.

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug384.pdf

Comment: I suppose it'll take some work, but this seems to be the best. Please edit your answer to include that comment, and then I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: There are very good reasons FPGA tools are designed to be used with primarily clocked logic. Complex combinatorial circuits are very hard to design in an FPGA. You would probably have to hand-place every resource, as if clocking is unspecified the routing delays could be quite random between synthesis runs. If your design really doesn't care about propagation delays you've got a chance... but if you care about these delays at all you're probably in for a painful and discouraging experience.

Comment: Thankfully, the delays don't matter that much, as it's given a task and then given time to solve the task.

Answer (score 4):

FPGAs are more than just gates (LUTs, FFs, Block RAM, Multipliers, etc) and trying to work out how many there are is a fairly meaningless exercise.  FPGA company marketing departments have, in the past, thrown numbers like equivalent gate counts equal to 1.4x the number of logic cells but I believe that they have stopped this practice.

If you are trying to determine whether a given design will fit in a FPGA it is best to do some trial synthesis runs on your HDL for various size FPGAs.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I still haven't started designing (and my design is directly in logic), because, I was going to design based on my FPGAs special offerings. I know I would need roughly >2.5M gates, so how would I find something that could hold that many gates?

Comment: How do you know you need 2.5M gates?

Comment: I started making one module out in a small simulator, multiplied by the number of modules I'd need, added a bit of space, and rounded up to two sig figs.

Comment: How did you get a gate count though?  The FPGA tools will give you usage numbers in terms of their resources, not gate counts.

Comment: I've been designing in a non-FPGA tool, namely, a mixed analog/digital simulator. And also on paper. The way I got a gate count was that I designed everything in gates instead of flip-flops and such.

Comment: As @The Photon said, FPGAs and their tools are heavily biased towards synchronous design techniques and you will get poor results doing otherwise.  At the end of the day though, if you want to design for a FPGA then use FPGA tools, not something else.

Comment: If I must use logic gates, what should I use? A CPLD doesn't have nearly enough gates.

Comment: Well, depends on what you want to do, you still can use FPGAs but for FPGAs, what you design in gates is not 'exactly'what you get after Place&Route, the tool maps your design into resources available inside the FPGA and then generates a report for you. From there you can determine the size of your design.

Answer (score 2):

Come at it the other way - it sounds from other comments like you have a module already sorted out.  Feed that to the FPGA tools - even the no-cost ones will give you an estimate of LUT/BRAM/FF count from the synthesis.  Multiply that up by your instance count, add some slack and there you have a usable LUT count for sizing the FPGA.

Of course, you may have to do it for each type of FPGA you consider as they each have somewhat different architectures, in terms of the number of inputs the LUTs have, and how much other supporting circuitry in the way of muxes etc they have around the LUTS.  And whether your circuit can take advantage of it...

Comment: Well, I would, if I could find a free FPGA tool that lets me simply draw out logic gates and then program an FPGA with it.

Comment: If you want a serious estimate, you might want to take your gates diagram and turn it into HDL.  You'll have to do that anyway to do any serious implementation work these days. Is it a very large "spaghetti" design or hierarchically structured with lots of reuse?

Comment: @haneefmubarak 8 years late, but there are plenty of drawing / simulation tools that can export verilog for example. So it's possible, atleast, in 2021 it is. Circuitverse is one of many free tools that could do this.